# sending files as messages through Hornetq from .net

Tags: c#, rest, jms, hornetq, stomp

We currently use HornetQ with JMS messaging from java apps to send files (BytesMessage - and some of them are quite large so we leverage large message support).

However, a new branch of the company has as C# app that needs to send messages (files with metadata) to integrate with the rest.

I took a brief look at STOMP and Rest API for hornetq but not sure if I could use them for binary but neither of them seems to clearly document how to send files as messages with some metadata that would be like the header of the message in JMS terminology.

Has anyone tried to do that or is there any other way to do the .net integration?

Thank you very much,

Greg

Comment: Have you looked at: http://www.wi1.uni-muenster.de/pi/lehre/ss11/EAI/tutorials/tutorial_jms_net.html

Comment: The solution is using Apache NMS (which works with STOMP). but in my experience, it has some issues. So i decided route messages from queue to a table (with Camel or a simple java program) and then with a timer in C#, read records from the table in short time periods.